# Remove slashes (both before and after) in relative post url

Tags: posts, customization, urls

I've seen a few "*remove last*" slash, but not how to remove both the first and last slash.

I've tried:

```
$post_url_rel = wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink( $post_id ));       

ltrim($post_url_rel, '/');                  

rtrim($post_url_rel, '/');
```

But it still says */postname/*

Anybody has any idea why this didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not actually putting the result of `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` back into the variable. Those functions *return* the trimmed value, they don't modify the passed variable. So you need to do this:

```
$post_url_rel = wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink( $post_id ));       
$post_url_rel = ltrim($post_url_rel, '/');                  
$post_url_rel = rtrim($post_url_rel, '/');
```

Or better yet, just use `trim()`, which will remove it from both ends:

```
$post_url_rel = wp_make_link_relative(get_permalink( $post_id ));        
$post_url_rel = trim($post_url_rel, '/');
```